# Setting state with delay via onMouseEnter in React component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu that consists of a series of Material UI's ListItems. When the mouse enters a given item, I use one of the props to lift up state to the parent component, which is in charge to determine which submenu it needs to show. Here are the relevant lines:

- `onMouseEnter` in each list item:

```
onMouseEnter={event => openDropDown(event, menuItem, subMenuItem)}
```

- `openDropDown` calls `setSubMenuItem` to lift up the state:

```js
  const openDropDown = (event, menuItem, subMenuItem) => {
    if (subMenuItem.subMenu) {
      setSubMenuItem({ ...subMenuItem, parent: menuItem });
      setAnchorEl(event.target.getBoundingClientRect());
    } else {
      closeDropDown();
    }
  };
```

However, the state transition is slower than the mouse movement. This causes the state to "get stuck" in the first item on the path to the destination. Thus, the submenu for items 2 and 6 are shown in scenarios A and B, respectively (instead of 4 and 3 as expected):

[image]

Any ideas to ensure that setting the state will be in sync with the mouse movement will be more than welcome. I tried calling `openDropDown` inside of a `setTimeout` but it results in each submenu popping up as I move from one item to the next.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code to make your situation more easily reproducible? would love to be able to copy-paste into a codesandbox to play around

Answer (score 0):

I ended up delaying the state transition as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466734/delay-react-onmouseover-event), and worked like a charm.